# How do you send a signal to a remote process in python?

Tags: python, signals

I've seen the signal module, it seems alright for installing signal handlers and setting up alarms but is sending a signal to another process done via, for example

```
os.system('kill -s SIGUSR2 8269')
```

And then is there a simple way to do this if the process is on a different host machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.kill()` for local processes, paramiko and the `kill` command for remote systems.